# Python multiprcessing on Windows with dynamic types

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
class Handler:
    pass

handler = type('HandlerClass', (int, Handler),{"const": [123]})
def stream_process(H):
    h=H()
    print(h.const)

processes = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=stream_process, args=( handler,), name=f"server #{i}") for i in range(4) ]

for process in processes:
    process.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

raises error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                      
  File "C:\Projects\winmp\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    process.start()
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 337, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 94, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.HandlerClass'>: attribute lookup HandlerClass on __main__ failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 108, in spawn_main
    source_process = _winapi.OpenProcess(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

this code also rises error

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
class Handler:
    pass


def stream_process(H):
    h = H()
    print(h.from_bytes(b'a', "big"))
    print(h.const)


def main():
    global HandlerClass
    HandlerClass = type('HandlerClass', (int, Handler),{"const": [123]})
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], "HandlerClass",HandlerClass )
    setattr(sys.modules['test'], "HandlerClass",HandlerClass )
    
    processes = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=stream_process, args=( HandlerClass,), name=f"server #{i}") for i in range(4) ]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 132, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'HandlerClass' on <module 'test' from 'C:\\Projects\\winmp\\test.py'>
```

I need construct type in main process, but init it in subprocess. How to solve this error?

On Linux and WSL it works.

this works, but class constructed 5 times. `{"const": [123]}` is very slow in real code, but constant. i not want to construct it on each process.

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
class Handler:
    pass


def stream_process(H):
    h = H()
    print(h.from_bytes(b'a', "big"))
    print(h.const)


HandlerClass = type('HandlerClass', (int, Handler),{"const": [123]})
print('HandlerClass constructed here', HandlerClass)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=stream_process, args=( HandlerClass,), name=f"server #{i}") for i in range(4) ]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Comment: on windows each child is the result of executing `python.exe` (because there is no fork) , they won't have the class in memory, and you will have to re-construct the class in each child regardless of what workaround you use to avoid writing it as a standard python class, so even if you could avoid writing it as a standard python class you won't solve your slowness issue.

Comment: @AhmedAEK, I know about spawn, no fork. I need workaround that not breaks Linux .  class bases may be different on different installations... I will try to transfer new class with queue...

Comment: This is a clear XY problem, the only reliable way to avoid recomputing these numbers is to save them on disk, and read them on the first invocation of the class methods, and not use any dyanically created class, maybe store all numbers in a configuration class object that is pickled to disk or sent as an argument to the subprocess, and avoid dynamic classes.

Comment: Python implements properties so you can fake whatever logic you need to store or read those numbers without the user knowing that he is not accessing a simple number

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the variable name and the `__qualname__` attribute of the class you create dynamically are mismatched (so `"handler" != "HandlerClass"`). That is to say, the attribute "HandlerClass" doesn't even exist in the module's namespace (only "handler" does). You can check this by running:

```
# AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'HandlerClass'
print(getattr(sys.modules[__name__], "HandlerClass"))
```

So the fix here is to change the line

```
handler = type('HandlerClass', (int, Handler),{"const": [123]})
```

to:

```
HandlerClass = type('HandlerClass', (int, Handler),{"const": [123]})
```

Comment: It also not works

Comment: @eri the minimal reproducible example you provided will work with the change provided above. The edited code you provided in the question now is not at all similar to the reproducible example. You have to create the dynamic class outside `main()` function, not inside, otherwise the child processes won't see the class since the part inside main will not be run for each process.

Comment: Not working on windows 10, python 3.10 and 3.12, outside main also not works as I needs